# Regular expression in htaccess file incorrectly matching root dir

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, shibboleth

I have the following .htaccess file on our xxx.yyy.edu site, in the root.

```
<FilesMatch "(.+)\.php">
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibUseHeaders On
    Require valid-user
    ShibRequestSetting redirectToSSL 443
</FilesMatch>
```

This should only match files that end in .php, and match all files that end in .php, then force authentication. That part of it appears to work fine.

However, it also matches the root url, http://xxx.yyy.edu and http://xxx.yyy.edu/. Which isn’t a good thing, since it is forcing the root of the site to be authenticated.

It does not match xxx.yyy.edu/index.htm, or any other url that has anything after the domain name, like xxx.yyy.edu/students.htm or even  xxx.yyy.edu/x

I’ve tested it in www.regexr.com, and it does not match the root url there.

Any thoughts/suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are getting authentication dialog because on your landing page default page is set to `index.php`.**

Have this `FilesMatch` with negative lookahead to avoid `index.php` from authentication:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!index\.php$).+?\.php$">
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
    ShibUseHeaders On
    Require valid-user
    ShibRequestSetting redirectToSSL 443
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I had discovered that it was the index.php, and had used #DirectoryIndex index.htm as a solution. However, I think your solution is better, and switched to it.
It also help me to better understand "negative lookahead, so double thanks! :-)
I'd mark up your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like perhaps it is matching the newline with the "dot" (a la XRegExp). Try something like `\w+:[\d\w\s\./]+\.php`.

Comment: Indeed. My bad, folks.

Comment: That's alright.  I didn't -1 you because you are new to posting and didn't want to half your rep :)